Who should I call about water intrusion around window during rainstorms?
We have a window that leaks around the upper interior trim during rainstorms, and I am not sure who to call to have this fixed. Roofing/gutters company, masonry, window installers?
The metal housing that goes across the top of the leaky window is part of our mini-split A/C system.
Photos


is your mini split conduit level with the top of the window? Does it allow water to drain away from the building?

Is the housing solely to protect the mini split lines, or does it serve another prupose?  Where is the actual water leak?

There's not a simple answer for this since it potentially involves several disciplines and it depends on what's available in your area.
I would want an exterior company to look at it who has credentials with masonry. The problem may be with the masonry, but it's more likely to be with window flashing or flashing around the HVAC equipment. The thing is, any fixes probably involve masonry.
So you don't want a shop that mostly does steel siding, for example, and a gutter company probably doesn't have the chops for masonry, either. My biggest concern would be that the masonry doesn't get messed up. Sheet metal can more easily be repaired or reworked than brick and mortar.
